# CocoaPods and Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, xcode8

I just want to try Swift 3.0 in one of my projects. Xcode open the migration window to update my project to use Swift 3.0.

The problem is, I just want to to update my project, and leave the Pods project untouched because any changes will be discard after I run the `pod install` again.

Anyone already have a solution for that?

Comment: actually it is possible..when you select to convert your project to swift 3..just uncheck the frameworks you dont want to convert in swift3...but i guess you will get a bunch of errors

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible.  Xcode builds your Cocoapods dependencies as well as your project.  You cannot mix Swift 2.x and Swift 3 code in the same project or use Cocoapods with Swift 3 that are written in Swift 2.x.

Comment: as stated by Anish, it's possible to do, but it's not enough to be able to build the project. He would have to change update the cocoa pods frameworks, but he would do it, not Xcode

Answer (score 5):

Just use the following commands in the end of your podfile and it sets up your pods file to have the frameworks take the swift 3 compiler or legacy compiler automatically so you do not get the cannot use swift 2.1 in swift 3 and errors like that.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Using this, have a look at the following example of my podfile. Just make sure the end statement is not before the block I have written above.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Project 1'

pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This might help [Swift migration guide](https://swift.org/migration-guide/#using-carthagecocoapods-projects)

**Straight from Swift.org**

> Using Carthage/CocoaPods Projects

If you are using binary Swift modules from other projects that are not built along with your project in your Xcode workspace, you can choose from one of the following migration strategies:

1. Include the source code of the project in your Xcode workspace With
   this approach you will build and migrate the open-source project
   along with your own project.
2. Use Xcode 7.3[.1] to make the necessary changes and validate that
   the project builds and links everything correctly.
3. Include the other Xcode project files in your workspace and setup
   your scheme for building the targets that your project depends on.
   If you have setup framework search paths for finding the binary
   Swift modules inside Carthage’s build folder, either remove the
   search paths or clean the build folder, so that you are sure that
   you are only using the Swift modules that are built from your Xcode
   workspace.

Wait until the upstream open-source project updates to Swift 2.3 or Swift 3

> You can follow this workflow for migrating your project:

1. Keep your project as it is building with Xcode 7.3
2. Invoke the migration assistant and apply the source changes that are
   suggested for your own project only (for Swift 2.3 or Swift 3)
3. Before trying to build, modify the Carthage/CocoaPods dependency
   file and specify the specific tag/branch of the project that is
   migrated to Swift 2.3 or Swift 3; update your dependencies and try
   to build your project with the updated dependencies and the source
   changes that you got from the migrator.

Answer (score 0):

any xcode in use latest cocoapods and remove cocoapods and again install latest with this step surly work in swift 3.0 i used in swift 3.0

0.sudo gem install cocoapods

1.cd (drag and drop your project folder)

2.sudo gem install cocoapods

3.touch podfile //create podfile

4.open -e podfile

5.platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end

6.ctrl+s

7.ctrl+q

8.pod install