# Migrating from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 with dependencies

Tags: cocoapods, swift3, xcode8, swift2

I am working on migrating my project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 but am having issues with 3rd party frameworks that I use via Cocoapods. Many of them have already upgraded to Swift 3, yet some of them haven't. When I build my project, I get the error:

> Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0: [...]

I have read answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39162269/406677) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484678/module-compiled-with-swift-2-3-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0), however they do not solve my problem. I cannot set `SWIFT_VERSION` to `2.3` if my project actually is using Swift 3, neither can I change those targets to have their `SWIFT_VERSION` set to 3.

Is there some way I can use the frameworks from my dependencies whom are compiled with Swift 2.3, in my Swift 3 project?

Comment: I think that, if you don't have sources for the libraries, you will need to wait until their developers release new versions.  I found this to be a clear summary: http://www.bensnider.com/abi-compatibility-whoopdty-do-what-does-it-all-mean.html

Comment: Thanks. @PhillipMills Thanks for the article as well. Makes more sense to me know. Answer the question and I'll accept the answer... whilst I'll start on updating those 3rd part libs myself ;)

Comment: @PaulPeelen Check if they have any stable **Swift3.0** branch i was able to make it work that way

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38682619/667586